# Margin-bottom is not working in "::before" pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I want to create a line above a text.
Everything is okay except margin-bottom which is not working!
[image]

Of course, the negative margin is working as I wish => margin-top: -.5em;
The line should have about 0.5 em from the bottom.

```css
.section-title {
  position: relative;
}

.section-title::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  width: 3em;
  height: .2em;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<header class="hero">
  <div class="section-center hero-center">
    <article>
      <div class="hero-info">
        <h2 class="section-title">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn hero-btn">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `margin-bottom` can only work if you set `bottom` to a value different than `auto`. But of course that's not what you want, so you will have to use negative `margin-top`.

Comment: I didn't set auto in my code

Comment: `auto` is the default value for `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom` properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) property instead.

```css
.section-title {
  position: relative;
  
  text-decoration: solid overline red .2em;
}

.hero {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header class="hero">
  <div class="section-center hero-center">
    <article>
      <div class="hero-info">
        <h2 class="section-title">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn hero-btn">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
<hr>
<header class="hero">
  <div class="section-center hero-center">
    <article>
      <div class="hero-info">
        <h2 class="section-title">Lorem, ipsum more ipsum.</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn hero-btn">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Why margin-bottom is not okay? Why does that work in some situations and not in others?

Comment: Because the `::before` is absolutely positioned so there is nothing after it to push or pull by the `margin-bottom` on that [stacking context](/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context). You remove `position: absolute;` and see it starts working because `.section-title` would be after the `::before` element.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.section-title {
  position: relative;
}

.section-title::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -.2em;
  width: 3em;
  height: .2em;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<header class="hero">
  <div class="section-center hero-center">
    <article>
      <div class="hero-info">
        <h2 class="section-title">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn hero-btn">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).